# Stylesheet array?

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig, assetic

From [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)

There is an example:

```
{% stylesheets '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/css/example.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

How could I implement a variable? Or an array?

**I know, that there is no official way.**

Can I use a `Twig Extension`? Or other things??

Anyone have an example for me??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean an array? The docs have an example for "Combining Assets". A variable is impossible and you shouldn't want that.

Comment: hmm i mean things like... `{% stylesheets '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/' ~ user.style ~ '/example.css' %}     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />{% endstylesheets %}`

Comment: As far as I know, this is currently not supported, and a limitation of assetic.

Comment: @PatrickKaiser indeed it's not supported because assetic parses templates only once. As a solution - don't use assetic for themed CSS resources.

Comment: @meze: What sould i use instead assetic? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that assetic 1.1 supports [variables](http://jmsyst.com/blog/asset-variables-in-assetic). With some limitations though - all possible values need to be known at compile-time - so you need to store values of styles in your config files.

In fact it's only a syntax sugar and it's not pure variables but it may be helpful in many cases.